# UI examples of functionality where a user can edit their profile, but all changes must be approved by an admin?

Tags: php

Does anyone know of any examples of this in terms of both front end (interface) and back end?  Thanks for your time!

Comment: This is a simple question with a very complex answer.

Comment: @BryanRoss, definitely.  I'm more just hoping for some UI examples, which I should make clearer.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of any specific UI examples of this, but the simplest way to handle the back end would be to have a database column `approved` as a `TINYINT(1), BIT, BOOL`, or whatever boolean field your RDBMS uses.

Any changes from the user force the `approved` column to a value of 0/FALSE.  The administrative approval queue merely has to select for rows `WHERE approved=FALSE`.